# SonarQube: including a subset of test coverage classes in report

Tags: sonarqube

I have Jenkins running JUnit tests and creating code coverage with Cobertura. This is imported to SonarQube, which shows all JUnit pass/fail and well as code coverage.

In addition to the full code coverage graphs report in SonarQube, I would like to include a timeline graph containing only a subset of the java classes from the coverage report. Haven't found a filter for this. I have found filters only for the full Sonar build, but this would require new Jenkins jobs and SonarQube projects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but you could try the following. It is not the best way but at least a possibility. You can still not manually select the subset of projects you want to show up, but this is for a good reason (names can change, another projects has the same name, etc...)

**Short form:**

you can configure a filter/measure and make use of filter-based charts and your projects dashboard.

**long form:**

Go to "Measure" within the topline. Now add some criteria for example:

```
"Components": Projects; "Components of": MyTestApplication; Key contains: myTest.
```

Search for it and save the filter. Once you done you can go back to the projects dashboard where you want your extra statistics. Click "Configure widgets" on the upper right. Now search for the keyword "filter". I did not checked them all but belive all of those results are able to use your filter created before. Select e.g. "Filter Motion Chart" and configure it.

Comment: Almost what we require. We have now created a measure which filters the java packages we want for the coverage. We are also able to list those on the dashboard. However we would still require 1) a total coverage based on filtered files (not all files), and 2) a chart showing how the coverage has evolved over time. The "Timeline" chart can only add Metrics, not Measures.

Comment: i don't think that there is a way to do so, at least I don't know any. But are you interessted into any statistic comming up from the other sources? I mean: you cuold set in-/exclusion filters for sources within Jenkins, so only your needed sources gets analyzed. But that is not a good idea if you still interessted in things like overall number of lines, etc.

Comment: Yeah, your final comments are what is stopping me from excluding files from analysis. I could ofcourse create new Sonar builds only for this, but would be cool if one Sonar build could be used for source. Sonar is a cool tool, but I've founds it's not very dynamic and configurable.

Comment: reffering to  http://www.sonarqube.org/resources/join-our-community/ you could try to send an mail to user@sonar.codehaus.org and see if they can help you. As some developers getting that mail too they will eventually add some possibilities in future updates. You can also direct to this thread so they can read of what you already have tried ;)